# How do I get a Mirror Image of a axml page I designed?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am making an application to get reflected output on a Heads-Up-Display.

Since the reflection is going to be inverted, I need to get the view inverted in the Phone itself to get accurate view on the HUD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your top-level layout container's X scale to be `-1`

```
android:scaleX="-1"
```

Or if you need a parallel surface reflection effect, set the `scaleY` to `-1`

[image]

#### Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleX="-1"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```